# re.search not getting the complete value

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to do a search in re of an  tag in an html im scraping, the thing is that every time I do the search the information is incomplete, for example, when I execute the code instead of putting the complete word it puts it in half, anyone knows why this is happening?

```py
d1 = sucursalesn[0]
substring = re.search("<address>(.*?)</address>", d1)
```

it puts <re.Match object; span=(263, 329), match= Montes Himalaya #905 int 10 Jar

instead of

it puts <re.Match object; span=(263, 329), match= Montes Himalaya #905 int 10 Jardines de la Concepción C.P. 20120, Aguascaliente>

Comment: Please add sample data, expected and actual results to your question to help debug it.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need the question mark in `(.*?)`.  Since `.*` is happy to match 0 characters, it's already optional.  And as a rule, it's almost always a bad idea to use regular expressions with HTML.  Use a parser, like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: To clarify, assuming `d1` is a string, please provide the result of `print(repr(d1))` in the above code, and what you expect `substring` to be.

Comment: @TimRoberts `.*?` is not "optionally match 0 or more characters", it is "non-greedily match 0 or more characters". It would make a difference if `d1` was e.g. `<address><address>X</address></address>`. (Though I fully agree on not using regexp on HTML)

Comment: I updated it so you can understand better